# When load the page through Ajax, some divs are misaligned, But if i resize the browser window all the divs are automatically arranging properly

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, symfony, jquery-masonry

I am loading all the pages in my symfony2 site through ajax calls. So the browser don't refresh. In some pages, Divs and images size is automatically setting wrong. So, the UI getting disturbed. But the Strange I didn't understand is if I resize the browser window or click on inspect element all the divs are automatically arranging properly. 
note: I am using external JS plugins mansory and mighty slider
I have debug the issue by placing all the css in external file but no luck.

I am loading the page like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: pageUrl + type,
    success: function (data) {
        var body = data.substring(data.indexOf("<body>")+6,data.indexOf("</body>"));
        $('#content').html('');
        $('#content').html(body);

        var scripts = data.substring(data.indexOf('<section id="scripts">'),data.indexOf('</section>'));            
        $('#scripts').html('');
        $('#scripts').html(scripts);

        var head = data.substring(data.indexOf("<head>")+6,data.indexOf("</head>"));
        $('head').html('');
        $('head').html(head);

    }, error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        location.reload();
        var error = xhr.responseText.substring(xhr.responseText.indexOf("<title>")+7,xhr.responseText.indexOf("</title>"));
        return false;


     }
});
```

After parsing the response I have tried different orders to load the head, body and scripts but no use.

Comment: Such help is required by a paid developer. Please do not post complicated tasks on this website. Otherwise if you have simple questions about the code please don't hesitate to ask. Thank you.

Comment: You probably have some listener on resize event, that is triggered when you resize your browser 'or inspect an element'

Comment: @mdma Yes i have a resize event listener and i commented it also. But still no change